# PHP encrypt/decrypt - AES-256-ECB

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to decrypt an email address using AES-256-ECB.
Its been a bit of a struggle as every source is showing a different method and I get a different result. Of course, I don't get the result I want. Please take it easy commenting on the code I tried - this function changed about a million times by now.

Desired output:
[https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'9cc25c7879fc94d5a19eeb8e47573b8423becb608a9a4e9d3c25c20aa7e04357'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'ECB','Raw','Hex','Ciphertext')AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'9cc25c7879fc94d5a19eeb8e47573b8423becb608a9a4e9d3c25c20aa7e04357'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'ECB','Hex','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':'undefined'%7D,''/disabled/breakpoint)&input=dGVzdHVzZXJAZ21haWwuY29t](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%279cc25c7879fc94d5a19eeb8e47573b8423becb608a9a4e9d3c25c20aa7e04357%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%27ECB%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%27Ciphertext%27)AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%279cc25c7879fc94d5a19eeb8e47573b8423becb608a9a4e9d3c25c20aa7e04357%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%27ECB%27,%27Hex%27,%27Raw%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27undefined%27%7D,%27%27/disabled/breakpoint)&input=dGVzdHVzZXJAZ21haWwuY29t)

Crap code:

```
function my_simple_crypt( $string, $action = 'e' ) {
    
    $secret_key = hex2bin('9cc25c7879fc94d5a19eeb8e47573b8423becb608a9a4e9d3c25c20aa7e04357');
 
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-ECB";

    //$secret_key = openssl_digest($secret_key, $encrypt_method, true);

    //$key = hash( 'sha256', $secret_key );
 
    if( $action == 'e' ) {

        $output = openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $secret_key, 3 );
        
        //$output = bin2hex($output);
        //$output = unpack('H*', $output);

    } else if( $action == 'd' ) {
        $output = openssl_decrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $secret_key, 3 );
        
        //$output = base64_encode($output);
        $output = bin2hex($output);
    }
    
    return $output;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(my_simple_crypt( 'testuser@gmail.com', 'e' ));
echo '</pre>';

echo 'Encrypt: ' . my_simple_crypt( 'testuser@gmail.com', 'e' ) . '<br>';
echo 'Decrypt: ' . my_simple_crypt( hex2bin('8dd714df21027133cd422d0301af3cb973374ee72008c3f9bd255f6d236da65e'), 'd' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your key and ciphertext are in **hex encoding** you need to convert them back to binary data before you
can feed them to the decryption function.

The following code gives this output:

```
plaintext decrypted: testuser@gmail.com
plaintext expected:  testuser@gmail.com
```

**Security warning: the following code uses the **UNSECURE ECB mode**:

```
<?php

$keyHex = '9cc25c7879fc94d5a19eeb8e47573b8423becb608a9a4e9d3c25c20aa7e04357';
$ciphertextHex = '8dd714df21027133cd422d0301af3cb973374ee72008c3f9bd255f6d236da65e';
$plaintextExpected = 'testuser@gmail.com';

$key = hex2bin($keyHex);
$ciphertext = hex2bin($ciphertextHex);

$plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-256-ecb', $key, true);
echo 'plaintext decrypted: ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL;
echo 'plaintext expected:  ' . $plaintextExpected . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you. So this is much simpler than I though. I have to use ECB as the cypher that comes as CBC is currently bugged in the system.